# SQL subquery or not?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I am trying to find a query that will select from two tables but not join those two tables as I don't want the result on one line.

Lets say I have these tables:

```
Persons1                 Persons2
Number Name    Surname   Number  Name   Surname
-----------------------  ------------------------- 
1      Peter   Miller    1       Frank  Farian 
2      Hans    Geige     2       Thomas Müller
```

And when I use this query:

```
SELECT
  NEW.NAME,
  OLD.NAME
FROM
  PERSONS1 NEW,
  PERSONS2 OLD
WHERE
  NEW.Number = 1 AND
  OLD.Number = 1
```

I get the following result:

```
Peter   Frank
```

How do I write the query to get:

```
Peter
Frank
```

Comment: Could you please give more explanation about the real case? it's not clear at all

Comment: Aside from your example being terrible.  Since you have a handle to both old and new using TableName (new) and TableName(OLD)  `(Old.Name=1 or new.name = 1)` in the where clause.  both results should be returned. as they are two rows in the table already.  or in this case... `Name =1` but that's where it falls apart in your example as you have no idea what name is and how name can be 1 and a name...  How do you know what name is old vs new in your example?  I see no column making that known.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the second table so I changed that. Is that better now?

Comment: How do you get `Peter` in your sample results, when you have a condition `NEW.NAME = 1`?

Comment: Still don't know how they relate. name=1 makes no sense.

Comment: So I aded 1 and 2 for the lines.

Comment: Shouldn't `WHERE` condition be `NEW.Number = 1` instead of `NEW.NAME = 1`?

Comment: Although we shouldn't edit code in questions, I feel that this was just a miss from the OP during his many edits. So fixed

Answer (score 8):

Use UNION for this:

```
SELECT NEW.NAME
FROM PERSONS1 NEW
WHERE NEW.Number = 1
UNION 
SELECT OLD.NAME
FROM PERSONS2 OLD
WHERE OLD.Number = 1
```

Comment: It's the correct idea, just a bad example in the question is throwing it off

Comment: Agreed  Right Idea example so bad couldn't confirm if this was correct.

Comment: This is the proof how good are the people who answers the questions. It was almost impossible to understand the question, and @dotnetcom came with the correct answer. Congratulations. +1

Comment: Thanx! that works in my main app. But as easy it actually look it does not work in DatabaseWorkbench 5.0.10. So that must be a bug there?

Comment: @MichaelMüller Could be, I don't have DatabaseWorkbench so I cannot verify that

Comment: With UNION ALL DBWorkbench works fine, its the other app that was not right.